# Highly independent means highly not co-related?

Tags: math, matrix, statistics, correlation

I have some problem in understanding the basic concepts of Matrices. I hope someone of you could help me in clearing my doubts.

A full rank matrix means all columns/rows are linearly independent to each other which drives the understanding of changing one column has no effect on the rest of the columns or being affected by other columns. I hope my concept till this point is right??
If the above understanding is right then can I say a full rank matrix means the columns are highly not co-related?

The reason for asking this question is to choose linearly independent and less inter co-related features for a traditional ML algo.

I hope someone can answer my query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,6] is liniarly independent to [1,2,3,4,5,5.999], but i would say their correlation is very high.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is off-topic here, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Notice also that question has nothing to do with `artificial-intelligence` (tag removed), and that your title does not make sense (two RVs are either independent or not, and independent RVs are by definition uncorrelated).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @desertnaut at first I am sorry for asking a theoretical question in this group. As well if a question is related to ML it is related to statistics and AI.

And thank you very much for clearing my doubt too  (two RVs are either independent or not, and independent RVs are by definition uncorrelated). 

I shall make sure in future not to ask theoretical questions here.

Comment: You are very welcome, and no worries; for your future reference, you may want to know that there is a dedicated SE forum for such ML/stats questions, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As for the AI tag, what I meant is that tags have to do with the *content* of the question, and not its *context*, so tagging such a math/stats question as `artificial-intelligence` is not appropriate, even though one of the dozens of applications may involve AI...